# Angular. Función no renderiza los cambios hasta que de un click en la pantalla

Tags: angular8

Tengo una funcion que agrega un nuevo registro y me retorna un objeto, el objeto lo añado al array, pero no se muestra en pantalla hasta hacer click en el algun lado de la pantalla. El componente es para usar un MatBottomSheet.

```html
this.comentariosService.postComentarioPbl(this.ModeloComentarioPbl)
          .subscribe(res => {

            console.log(res); //Linea 93
           
            let object = res as GetComentarioPbl; 
            this.ModeloComentarioPbl = new ComentarioPbl();

            this.arrayComentarioPbl.splice(0, 0, object); // ==> Aqui añado el objeto al array de comentarios
            this.countComentarios=this.countComentarios +1;
            this.readonlyTxtPbl = false;

          });
```

En la imagen se aprecia que la consola muestra que ya recibi el objeto, incluso se muestra
la linea del ts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

En el constructor

```
public appRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
```

El código:

```
this.comentariosService.postComentarioPbl(this.ModeloComentarioPbl)
      .subscribe(res => {

        console.log(res); //Linea 93
       
        let object = res as GetComentarioPbl; 
        this.ModeloComentarioPbl = new ComentarioPbl();

        this.arrayComentarioPbl.splice(0, 0, object); // ==> Aqui añado el objeto al array de comentarios
        this.countComentarios=this.countComentarios +1;
        this.readonlyTxtPbl = false;
        this.appRef?.detectChanges();
      });
```

De esta forma obligas a Angular a detectar cambios.

Comment: Gracias! Efectivamente, el tema era el detector de cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Varios detallitos:

```
this.arrayComentarioPbl.splice(0, 0, object);
```

se puede poner más elegante así:

```
this.arrayComentarioPbl.unshift(object); //insertar en la primera posición
```

Pero en cualquier caso creo que lo que falla es que Angular no sabe que has modificado el array: lo que comprueba son los cambios de objeto, pero el array sigue siendo el mismo aunque modificado.

Debería funcionar si usas

```
this.arrayComentarioPbl = [object].concat(this.arrayComentarioPbl;
```